# How do I disassemble the fill valve on a Kohler toilet?

Tags: plumbing

Kohler elongated toilet runs constantly after refilling.  Float does not move up to shut off the flow.

Comment: you provided almost no information ...... why does the float stay down? .... what happens if you lift the float?

Comment: Take the float off and see if it can still float - easy first test...